# Cross reference to align

Tags: cross-referencing, align

What I want to do is to make a cross reference to program (P) and still be able to make cross references to each separate line in the alignment.

```
\begin{align}
  (P)\quad \min &cx\label{objective}\\
  s.t.: & Ax\geq b\label{firstConst}\\
        & Dx\geq d\label{secondConst}\\
        & x\in\{0,1\}\label{binary}
 \end{aling}
```

I known that I can use gather-aligned to make a reference to the program, but then I do not have the possibility to make references to separate lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of our site.

Comment: Is it a program or an equation system?

Comment: It is a integer linear program. That is minimize a linear function (objective) subject to the linear constraints firstConst and secondConst given the variables are binary.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel For historical reasons, those optimisation problems are known as programs (linear program, mixed-integer program etc.). I think George Dantzig is to blame :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `subequations` to number the individual contraints, and tag the whole program with `P`. At least that is something I've seen in some books:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  a = b
\end{equation}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{P}
\begin{subequations}\label{ip}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{align}
  \min &\ cx\label{objective}\\
  \text{s.t.}\qquad Ax & \geq b\label{firstConst}\\
        Dx & \geq d\label{secondConst}\\
        x  & \in\{0,1\}\label{binary}
 \end{align}
\end{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
The binary program~\eqref{ip}, the objective~\eqref{objective}, the constraint~\eqref{firstConst}.

\begin{equation}
  c = d
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: +1 The numbering scheme is much more elegant than in my solution. I disapprove of the lack of horizontal alignment, though.

Comment: @Jubobs What alignment would you like to have, `min` and `s.t.`?

Comment: Yes, I think the program would be easier to parse that way, but it's just my personal preference. Do what you think is best :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a `subequations` environment, in which you can have a label (placed outside the `align` environment) for reference to the whole binary linear program. That approach allows you to have one label for each individual line of the program.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\label{myILP}
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}   \quad & cx            \label{objective} \\
\text{subject to} \quad & Ax \geq b     \label{firstConst}\\
                        & Dx \geq d     \label{secondConst}\\
                        & x \in \{0,1\} \label{binary}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\noindent In binary linear program~\ref{myILP},
\eqref{objective} correponds to the (linear) objective,
\eqref{firstConst} and \eqref{secondConst} correspond to
(linear) inequality constraints,
and \eqref{binary} correspond to the binary constraint. 
\end{document}
```